# How to grab a hidden fields value using PHP

Tags: php, html, post, forms, http-post

I was wondering how can I grab the value from a hidden field using PHP?.

Here is the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="' . $row['delete_id'] . '" />
```

Comment: please notiche that the trailing `/>` is XHTML, **not HTML**. It will validate HTML Transitional but will not validate HTML Strict. Better not to use it, since it's either plain wrong or at least less correct. For more info: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html

Comment: @Lo'oris - Why is it better not to use XHTML? Why is it wrong or less correct? In this case you don't know what DOCTYPE TaG has declared.

Comment: I assumed he was using HTML because he added to the question the tag "html".

Comment: I tried and failed to upvote the first comment, then I noticed it was mine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

exactly like a non-hidden value.

```
$_POST["delete"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume the hidden field is in a form. So give it an id and do it like you normally would get the value from an input field

```
$_POST["delete"]
```

Comment: the `id` is relevant to JS only, for the POST only the `name` matters, and it's already there.

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `$_REQUEST['delete']`

Answer (score 0):

if you use post method use $_POST['delete'];
if you use get method use $_GET['delete']; 
Or for both method use $_REQUEST['delete'];